# Problema em Inserir num Array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boas, estou a tentar aprender python pois parece-me uma linguagem com algum interesse aplicabilidade nas mais diversas áreas (e interessa-me para o raspberry).

Á medida que vou aprendendo gosto de ir desevolvendo alguma coisa para aplicar os conhecimentos.

Como tal estou a desenvolver um sistema constituído por um dicionario de turmas(Classe Criada) cujo identificador de cada turma é a sigla recebida.

Cada turma é constituída por um array de alunos(Classe Criada) e uma sigla que a identifica.

Todas as classes possuem setters e getters para todos os atributos.

O meu problema é que sempre que adiciono um novo aluno a uma turma já criada e inserida no array de turmas, este adiciona-o a todas as turmas contidas no array e não consigo encontrar o foco do problema.

O código da minha classe turma é o seguinte:

```
class Turma:
   nome = None
   sigla = None
   alunos = []
   def __init__(self, _nome, _sigla):
       self.nome = _nome
       self.sigla = _sigla
   def getNome(self):
       return self.nome
   def addAluno(self, _aluno):
       self.alunos.append(_aluno)
   def getSigla(self):
       return self.sigla
   def getAlunos(self):
       return self.alunos
```

O código da minha classe aluno é o seguinte:

```
class Aluno:
   nome = None
   idade = None
   numero = None
   def __init__(self, _nome, _idade, _num):
       self.nome = _nome
       self.idade = _idade
       self.numero = _num
   def getNome(self):
       return self.nome
   def getNumero(self):
       return self.numero
   def getIdade(self):
       return self.idade
   def setNome(self, _nome):
       self.nome = _nome
   def setIdade(self, _idade):
       self.idade = _idade
   def setNome(self, _num):
       self.numero = _num
```

No meu ficheiro de controlo do sistema tenho as seguintes funcionalidades:

```
turmas = {}
def createTurma():
   nome = input("Insira o nome da turma: ")
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla da turma: ")
   turmas[sigla] = Turma(nome, sigla)
   print(turmas);
   print("Turma Adicionada com Sucesso!")

def listTurma():
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla do curso: ")
   print(turmas[sigla].getNome())

def addAlunoTurma():
   num = 0
   nome = input("Insira o nome do aluno: ")
   idade = input("Insira a idade do aluno: ")
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla da turma: ")
   _aluno = Aluno(nome, idade, 0)
   turmas[sigla].addAluno(_aluno)

def getAlunosByTurma():
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla da turma: ")
   teste = turmas[sigla].getAlunos()
   print(len(teste))
   for i in turmas[sigla].getAlunos():
       print("Nome: " + i.getNome())
       print("Numero: " + str(i.getNumero()))
       print("--------------")
```

Detectei este problema quando a função getAlunosByTurma() pois independente da sigla imprime sempre todos os alunos.

Obrigado!!

Comment: Para saber o que está errado aí, é necessário ver o código das classes. O problema parece estar no méotod `getSigla` .

Com o tempo, você vai entender melhor Pythone ver que  getters e setters explícitos não são necessários na maioria dos casos - e quando são, eles funcionam implicitamente  - sem ter que serem chamados como métodos (properties).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
Já complementei um pouco mais a minha duvida para que seja possível ter uma melhor ideia do problema e alterei o array para um dicionario, para ser mais simples chegar a turma que quero!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema está nessa declaração da classe turma, em conjunto com um erro
comum com quem vem de Java para Python:

```
class Turma:
   nome = None
   sigla = None
   alunos = []
   def __init__(self, _nome, _sigla):
       self.nome = _nome
       self.sigla = _sigla
```

A "declaração de variáveis" no corpo da classe é incorreta e desnecessária em Python: isso cria atributos da **classe** e não para cada instância como acotnece em Java.

Via de regra, isso não é problema por que quando você cria um valor para `self.nome` no `__init__`, com `self.nome = nome`, é criado um atributo na instância do objeto que "esconde" o atributo da classe.

Mas no caso de `alunos` você cria uma lista vazia - e seus métodos não criam uma nova lista - eles só manipulam a lista em `self.alunos`. Não havendo um atributo da instância que seja `self.alunos`, o Python  automaticamente acessa o atributo em `self.__class__.alunos` - que é uma única lista que é compartilhada por todas as suas instâncias de `Turma`.

Corrigir isso é bem fácil  - simplesmente altere o início da sua declaração de `Turma` para:

```
class Turma: 
   def __init__(self, _nome, _sigla):
       self.nome = _nome
       self.sigla = _sigla
       self.alunos = []
```

Outra dica: o objeto literal construido com `[]` é uma "lista" (list), não um "array". Pode usar a palavra "lista" mesmo. E outra: não há nenhuma necessidade, d prefixar as variáveis locais com "*" - você deve ter lido que se convenciona que atributos e métodos privados são prefixados com "*" - sim, o entnaot isso é uma convenção - não há nada mágico na linguagem a respeito de variáveis que começam com `_` (mas há para atributos que começam com dois `__`, cuidado). Ademais, você está prefixando variáveis locais dos métodos com "_"  - essas variáveis são internas aos métodos, e não são visíveis "de fora" - não há qualquer ganho - nem convencional - em chamar seu parâmetro de  `_idade` e  não de `idade` - mas você perde em legibilidade e facilidade de digitação.

E, como disse acima, em geral você não precisa de getters e setters: o seu programa funcionará igualmente bem se quem quiser alterar a idade de um aluno faça "aluno.idade=12" em vez de "aluno.setIdade(12)" - Por conta do GIL, essas atribuições diretas são thread-safe.  E se em algum momento você quiser colocar um guarda nos atributos (o sistema cresceu e você quer evitar idades que não sejamm números inteiros positivos maiores que 5, por exemplo) - aí você escreve o getter e o setter,  mas usando "property" do Python - os usuários da sua classe continuam escrevendo `aluno.idade = 12` mas dessa vez a atribuição vai passar pelo método setter.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei bem como as suas classes estão estruturadas, mas faço ideia do programa que está a fazer. Fiz um pequeno exemplo que creio que seja capaz de lhe dar umas luzes. Aqui, usando [dicionários](http://www.programeempython.com.br/blog/estruturas-de-dados-em-python-dicionarios/) conseguimos armazenar as informações relevantes aos alunos e respetivas turmas

```
turmas = []

def createTurma():
   nome = input("Insira o nome da turma: ")
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla da turma: ")
   turmas.append({'nome': nome, 'sigla': sigla, 'alunos': []})

def addAlunoTurma():
   num = 0
   nome = input("Insira o nome do aluno: ")
   idade = input("Insira a idade do aluno: ")
   sigla = input("Insira a sigla da turma: ")
   if any(turma['sigla'] == sigla for turma in turmas): # verificamos se a sigla existe
        for turma in turmas:
            if sigla == turma['sigla']:
                turma['alunos'].append({'nome': nome, 'idade': idade})
                break
   else:
        print('turma não existe')

createTurma()
print(turmas)
addAlunoTurma()
print(turmas)
addAlunoTurma()
print(turmas)
```

A titulo de exemplo, aqui vamos adicionar uma turma e dois alunos, no final vamos ter as turmas neste formato:

```
[{'nome': 'turma B1', 'sigla': 'B1', 'alunos': [{'nome': 'Miguel', 'idade': '30'}, {'nome': 'caoc10', 'idade': '25'}]}]
```

Em que para aceder aos dados da primeira turma faria:

```
turmas[0] # {'nome': 'turma B1', 'sigla': 'B1', 'alunos': [{'nome': 'Miguel', 'idade': '30'}, {'nome': 'caoc10', 'idade': '25'}]}
```

Comment: Sua resposta simpleemten remove toda a Orientação a Objetos da aplicação - é bem difícil imaginar isso como um "fix".  :-) Apesar de que, sim, se essa for toda a funcionalidade do programa, dicionários funcionarão bem.

Comment: Sim @jsbueno claro, tal como disse não sei como as classes estão estruturadas. Acredito que facilmente conseguirá implementar uma coisa assim e resolver o problema, o focu do problema não tem nada a haver com oop mas sim com inserção num array, que presumo que seja uma lista

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
Já complementei um pouco mais a minha duvida para que seja possível ter uma melhor ideia do problema e alterei o array para um dicionario, para ser mais simples chegar a turma que quero!
A solução dada funciona, no entanto gostava de manter o foco numa OOP e perceber qual o problema para que no futuro não cometa o mesmo erro!!